# Top aligning something with Css

Tags: html, css

I'm just starting to look at html/css and having some problems getting my head around how the layout engine works.

I'm from a c# background and anything with hardcoded widths/heights feels like something is wrong.  One of the first things I discovered is that you can't make divs expand to fill their available height in a sensible way, so I've been using tables.

The UI I want is basically a grid, which is the main part of the page with a side panel.  The idea is to navigate the grid with the arrow keys and then select options for a cell using the side panel - its a fairly straightforward master/detail.

I'm happy with using a table to seperate the two columns but the problem I'm running into is in the side panel:

I want to have a search box at the top.  When you type into the search box it 'autocompletes' to show you a options relevant to what you just typed.

The first problem I had was that the search box wasn't at the top of the cell in the grid.  So I was using:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
```

for the `<input>` with a `position:relative` set in the td.

I was then using another `div` inside the cell to layout the results.  That works fine but the search box obscures the first item.

I then tried changing the search box to have `display: block` which solves the problem but means the search box isn't top aligned when there are no search results!

It seems like using the `display` and `position` attributes are mutually exclusive so how do I achieve this in a sensible way?

One option seems to be to just use tables for everything, is there anything wrong with that?

```css
#mainLayout
{
    width: 100%
}

#turnSelectionPanel
{
    /*visibility: hidden;*/
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: saddlebrown;
    /*this is to allow positioning within this element using 'absolute'*/
    position: relative;
}

#turnSearchBox
{
    min-height: 20px;
    max-width: 200px;
    min-width: 100px;
    display: block;
    /*or
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    */
}
```

```html
    <body>

    <table id="mainLayout">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table id="roster"></table>
            </td>
            <td id="turnSelectionPanel">
                <input type="text" id="turnSearchBox"/>
                <div id="turnArea">

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    </body>
```

I've ommitted some of the other css for brevity's sake + some of the stuff shown there is basically irrelevant - widths etc.

The table + sidepanel is populated from javascript

Comment: Please don't use tables for layout. Please, just don't.

Comment: Using tables is an allowable, but it is considered ugly and outdated and is longer popular method for laying out pages. Generally <div> is used to create the same, but more controllable structure. To get your search bar flush with the top of the page just move the <div> with the search bar above your right column.

Comment: You might want to learn how the `position` style works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: @jbutler483 I've seen a similar sentiment expressed elsewhere, why is that?

Comment: @JonnyLeeds: When you're trying to 'push the boundaries' with css, the tabular layouts will cause *nightmares* with styling. Also, Tables are *designed* for one thing - tabular data. **not layout**. So hence, the importance of using divs and using positioning is heavily stressed. [See more here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a basic structure that you can you use.

```
<body>
  <!-- This is a wrapper that controls the total height and width of page elements -->
  <div id="mainLayout"> 

    <!-- You can position the elements however you would like. -->
    <div id="leftColumn"> ...Code goes here... </div>
    <div id="searchBar"> ...Code goes here... </div>
    <div id="rightColumn"> ...Code goes here... </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I am particularly fond of using `float:left;` to arrange my  elements. Something like:

```
#mainLayout {
    width:100%
    height:100%;
}
#leftColumn {
    width:75%;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
}
#searchBar{
    width:25%;
    height: 10%;
    float:left;
}
#rightColumn {
    width:25%;
    height: 90%;
    float:left;
}
```

This will create a layout that scales with the window, and gives you a left column and a right column with a search bar above it. Obviously if you know what size you want your elements than you can simply set them.

Comment: I would avoid floating elements, although that's more personal preference. It's much easier to use `positioning` and `display` css properties instead.

Comment: @jbutler483 could you provide an example of how you would do this?

Comment: @sring thanks for the response.  This works and I can sort of see what's going on here

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a fan (at all, really) of using floats, so this is my approach on your layout:

I'm not sure if you want a left column, but I've added one in for your choice anyway:

```css
.left, .nav,.right, .content {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  position: absolute;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.nav {
  width: 75%;
  background: lightgray;
  height: 100px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.left {
  width: 20%;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  background: darkgray;
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
}
.right {
  width: 25%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: gray;
  height: 100%;
}
.content {
  width: 55%;
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  background: lightblue;
  top: 100px;
  left: 20%;
}
#search {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;

  margin: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">I'll go most of the way along the top</div>
<div class="left">I'll be a column on the left</div>
<div class="right">
  <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search Me" />
  <br/>
  <div class="furtherContent">
    I'll be a column on the right</div>
</div>
<div class="content">I'll be a content</div>
```

Comment: thanks, definitely useful to see another way of doing things.  Not had chance to mess around with it properly yet... I've not come acrosss calc before, that looks useful

Comment: @JonnyLeeds: Example is exactly that: an example: if you're only getting into css, I would advise to (a) steer clear of floating elements, and (B) steer clear of bootstrap - I've used it and hated it, plus there's 100's of questions about it posted daily.

Comment: thanks.  Yeah I'm not a big fan of libraries/frameworks - think you should understand the problem they are solving before using them because they always come with a cost.  I didn't downvote you btw - I've got this upvoted - thanks for your help

Comment: @JonnyLeeds: I've not used a library? Css is *used for describing the look and formatting of a document written in a markup language* [~Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets)

Comment: Yeah I know you were warning off using bootstrap and I agree with you - I want to learn about css before I use something to help me with it/do it for me